# Using JQuery with ASP.NET for slideToggle

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, slidetoggle

I want to slideToggle a bulleted list in ASP.NET using jQuery when I click a button. The C# code behind will update the bulleted list by calling a web service and displaying the data.

Would I have to call the jQuery function from the C# code after the C# code has finished? Has anyone got an example to show?

Here is my code, which I will keep simple:

Page code:

```
<asp:BulletedList runat="server" id="resultsList">
</asp:BulletedList>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Search" id="searchBtn" 
onclick="searchBtn_Click" />
```

C# code behind for button:

```
resultsList.Item.Add( "New Item");
//do other stuff to list
```

jQuery code on page:

```
$("#searchBtn").click(function () {
        $("#resultsList").slideToggle('slow', function () {
            //do something
        });
});
```

Although it doesn't work. Is it because i'm not calling the jQuery code from the C# code behind?

Comment: When do you load the list on page load, from the server or button click?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli On page load I do not touch the list, so it is effectively empty. I only add data to it on the server side when the button is clicked.

Comment: Do you make an AJAX call to fetch the list information on button click?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli I haven't implemented an AJAX call yet. Its a full post back each time the button is clicked.

Comment: Then you need to make an ajax call get the list, bind it and then slideToggle the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution

```
$("#searchBtn").click(function () {

  if(!$("#resultsList").data("listBound")){

  $.ajax({
    url: "urlWhichWillReturnListMarkUpOrJsonResult",
    succcess: function(response){
       //If the response is just the requried markup
       $("#resultsList").html(response).slideToggle('slow');
       //If the response is a json result then you have to write a logic to read the response and create the required markup for the list and append that markup to resultList container and then call slideToggle method.

       //Once the list is populated set at flag using data attributes so that next time when u click u dont have to make ajax call but just slideToggle it
      $("#resultsList").data("listBound", true);
    }
  });
}
else
{
    $("#resultsList").slideToggle('slow');
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it working with a very simple web service method. But for a more complex method it doesn't. I think it may be due to a delay while the method is running (takes a few seconds to complete). I'm returning a List of strings by json, i'm pretty sure I have the jQuery correct to print them out but the request keeps failing for some reason.

Comment: Yeah sure, no problem. As it does answer my question. It appears I have a slightly different question now anyway so i'll probably start a new question later if I don't find the answer soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add code below as the very last string of the searchBtn_Click method:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ToogleResultsList", string.Format("$('#{0}').slideToggle('slow', function () { alert('Foo!'); });", resultsList.ClientID), true);
```

Comment: I don't really want to call the script this way if I can get away with it, but thanks for the info.